# how to remove whitespace in css from title

Tags: css

i am trying to place a title above some words but my title has a white space underneath, my css is

```css
.title{
  grid-template-areas:"image" "title"
}

.title_word{
   grid-area: title;
}

.title_img{
  grid-area: img;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
<p class="title_word">hello</p>
<img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5549/10549969363_76ccf43946_b.jpg" alt="not working" class="title_img">
</div>
```

as you can see, this works but in firefox and chrome it is giving me lots of white space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding  `margin-bottom: 0` to the title class will do the job. the reason for that is because margins are used to create space around elements, outside of the defined borders so setting it to 0 will eliminate that extra gap.

the `<p>` tag has a default css property of `margin-block-end: 1em;` which is causing that extra gap you see.

```css
.title{
  grid-template-areas:"image" "title"
}

.title_word{
   grid-area: title;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title_img{
  grid-area: img;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
<p class="title_word">hello</p>
<img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5549/10549969363_76ccf43946_b.jpg" alt="not working" class="title_img">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your time i have tried all these and they work 

Comment: No problem my friend. I would appreciate the vote up and accept answer if you could please (:

Comment: sorry i do not have enough reputation to upvote you but i will acceot your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the whitespace underneath add:

```
margin-bottom: 0;
```

to your

```
.title
```

In the end it should look like this.

```
.title {
    grid-template-areas:"image" "title"
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time i have tried all these and they work 

Answer (score 0):

Before I start tinkering with CSS - I add an `*` selector, which removes default margins and padding.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.title{
  grid-template-areas:"image" "title"
}

.title_word{
   grid-area: title;
}

.title_img{
  grid-area: img;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
<p class="title_word">hello</p>
<img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5549/10549969363_76ccf43946_b.jpg" alt="not working" class="title_img">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your time i have tried all these and they work 

Answer (score -1):

This is likely because of the margin that html things tend to have. try a `margin: 0;` or a `margin-bottom: 0;` if that doesn't work, try the same with the `border: 0;` and `padding: 0;` as that's what makes up the whole block.

Comment: thank you for your time i have tried all these and they work 